Find the segment $AC$ in the triangle below
Calculate $AC$ if $BP = PC$, $AB = 9m$ e $CD = 6m$
(Answer:15m)
I try

$ \angle PBC = 180^o -2\beta$
$\triangle CPB: \angle PBC \cong \angle PCB = 180^o -2\beta$
$ \angle CPB = 4\beta - 180^o$
$\triangle ABP: 4\beta- 180^o = \beta+2\theta$
$ \therefore 3\beta = 60^o +\frac{2 \theta}{3}$
$ \frac{BD}{AB} = \frac{CD}{AC} \implies \frac{BD}{9}=\frac{6}{AC}$
$ \therefore AC = \frac{54}{BD}$
$ \triangle ACD: \angle ADC = \theta + 180^o -2\beta$
How do I finish?

Notice $\angle\mathrm{BPA}=2\angle\mathrm{BCA}$


Let $CE\parallel BP$, intersecting with $AB$ at $E$. Then $\angle CEB=\angle ABP=\angle CBE$, so $CB=CE$.
Note that $\angle ACB=\angle PBC=\angle BCE$, so $D$ is the incenter of $\triangle ACE$. Thus $ED$ is the bisector of $\angle BEC$.
Let $BD=x$. Then $CE=BC=x+6$. Since $\frac{BE}{BD}=\frac{CE}{CD}$, $BE=\frac{x(x+6)}{6}$. Similarly, $\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{AC}{CD}$, so $AC=\frac{54}{x}$.
Finally, use the formula of angle bisector, $BC^2=AC\cdot CE-AB\cdot BE$. We have
$$(x+6)^2=(x+6)\frac{54}{x}-9\cdot \frac{x(x+6)}{6}$$
which gives $x=\frac{18}{5}$, so $AC=\frac{54}{x}=15$.

Excellent,,,thanks for help
